# When does the SQL Server write the results of each Set Statement In and UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two update statements.  Both are similar but operate on different sets of tables. One works, the other doesnt. I am not sure why.

I have a table called UPLOAD. It contains the results of a parse from another data system.

- VendorText (nVarChar(50))
- VendorID (BigInt)
- ModelText (nVarChar(50)
- ModelID (BigInt)
- UnitText (nVarChar(50))
- UnitID (BigInt)
- SubUnitText (nVarChar(50))
- SubUnitID (BigInt)

Intially the four text fields are filled in from the parse.

There are four tables that we are pulling information from.

- VendorTable
- ModelTable
- UnitTable
- SubUnitTable

The Model table has an integer field that links it to the Vendor Table.

The Subunit table has an integer field that links it to the Unit Table.

There are four Scalar Functions that we use.

- FindVendor  - Takes a text value and searches the Vendor Table for
  the name and returns the PK.
- FindModel - Takes a text value and and integer value (PK of the
  Vendor).  Returns the PK of the Model Number.
- FindUnit - Takes a text value and searches the UnitTable for a match 
  and returns the PK of the unit.
- FindSubUnit - Takes a text value and an integer value(PK of the UNIT)
  and returns the PK of the SubUnit.

UPDATE STATEMENT THAT WORKS

```
UPDATE UPLOADTABLE
  SET
      VendorID = FindVendor(VendorText),
      ModelID = FindModel(ModelText, VendorID)
```

I have tested this and it gives the proper results.

This however fails.

```
UPDATE UPLOADTABLE
  SET
      UNITID = FindUnit(UnitText),
      SubUnitID = FindSubUnit(SubUnitText, UnitID)
```

All I get back are Zero's in the SubUnitID.

This however does work.

```
UPDATE UPLOADTABLE
  SET
     UnitID = FindUnit(UnitText);

UPDATE UPLOADTABLE
  SET
     SubUnitID = FindSubUnit(SubUnitText, UnitID)
```

Not sure why the first one works and the second one fails. Unless the UPDATE for the model number is just working by chance.  I dont know when the update statement writes the results of eadch of the Set statements.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming no triggers are defined, and neither update violates any constraints, the difference between

```
UPDATE UPLOADTABLE SET
  UNITID = FindUnit(UnitText),
  SubUnitID = FindSubUnit(SubUnitText, UnitID)
```

and

```
UPDATE UPLOADTABLE SET
  UnitID = FindUnit(UnitText);
UPDATE UPLOADTABLE SET
 SubUnitID = FindSubUnit(SubUnitText, UnitID)
```

is that in the first case, the `UnitID` that gets passed to `FindSubUnit` is the old value of `UnitID`: you haven't updated it yet. If `UPDATE` did not work that way, you would not be able to write swapping statements like `UPDATE table SET field1 = field2, field2 = field1`. You would be able to execute that, but it would not do what you would want.

One possible way to write it in a single update is

```
UPDATE UPLOADTABLE SET
  UNITID = FindUnit(UnitText),
  SubUnitID = FindSubUnit(SubUnitText, FindUnit(UnitText))
```

Comment: Thank you hvd, I found the issue, the Model/Vendor only appeared to be working properly, there was a bug in the lookup function for the Model Number. You did however anwer my question about when the Update statement writes its results. Thanks, it pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an answer to your question, and I think hvd has already explained how the update statement works, so I think the key to answering your question is in the definition of the UDF `FindModel`. However, I thought I would point out you can perform all these updates at once without any problems (and more efficiently) by simply using JOINs in the update:

```
UPDATE  UPLOADTABLE
SET     VendorID = v.VendorID,
        ModelID = m.ModelID,
        UnitID = ut.UnitID,
        SubUnitID = s.SubUnitID
FROM    UPLOADTABLE u
        LEFT JOIN VendorTable v
            ON v.VendorText = u.VendorText
        LEFT JOIN ModelTable m
            ON m.VendorID = v.VendorID
            AND m.ModelText = u.ModelText
        LEFT JOIN UnitTable ut
            ON v.UnitText = ut.UnitText
        LEFT JOIN SubUnitTable s
            ON s.UnitID = v.UnitID
            AND s.SubUnitText = u.SubUnitText;
```

Comment: Thanks Gareth. I am going to try this and see if it helps speed things up.